# Curl not downloading files correctly

Tags: bash, curl

So I have been struggling with this task for eternity and still don't get what went wrong. This program doesn't seem to download ANY pdfs. At the same time I checked the file that stores final links - everything stored correctly. The $PDFURL also checked, stores correct values. Any bash fans ready to help?

```
    #!/bin/sh

    #create a temporary directory where all the work will be conducted
    TMPDIR=`mktemp -d /tmp/chiheisen.XXXXXXXXXX`
     echo $TMPDIR

    #no arguments given - error
    if [ "$#" == "0" ]; then
          exit 1
    fi

    # argument given, but wrong format
    URL="$1"

    #URL regex 
    URL_REG='(https?|ftp|file)://[-A-Za-z0-9\+&@#/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-A-Za-z0-9\+&@#/%=~_|]'

    if [[ ! $URL =~ $URL_REG ]]; then
          exit 1
    fi

    # go to directory created
    cd $TMPDIR

    #download the html page
    curl -s "$1" > htmlfile.html

    #grep only links into temp.txt
    cat htmlfile.html | grep -o -E 'href="([^"#]+)\.pdf"' | cut -d'"' -f2 > temp.txt

    # iterate through lines in the file and try to download
    # the pdf files that are there
    cat  temp.txt | while read PDFURL; do

    #if this is an absolute URL, download the file directly
    if [[ $PDFURL == *http* ]]
    then

        curl  -s -f -O $PDFURL
        err="$?"
        if [ "$err" -ne 0 ]
        then
              echo ERROR "$(basename $PDFURL)">&2
        else
              echo "$(basename $PDFURL)"
        fi

    else

         #update url - it is always relative to the first parameter in script
         PDFURLU="$1""/""$(basename $PDFURL)"
         curl -s -f -O $PDFURLU
         err="$?"
         if [ "$err" -ne 0 ]
         then
             echo ERROR "$(basename $PDFURLU)">&2
         else
             echo "$(basename $PDFURLU)"
         fi
       fi

      done


#delete the files
rm htmlfile.html
rm temp.txt
```

P.S. Another minor problem I have just spotted. Maybe the problem is with the if in regex? I pretty much would like to see something like that there:

```
if [[ $PDFURL =~ (https?|ftp|file):// ]]
```

but this doesn't work. I don't have unwanted parentheses there, so why?

P.P.S. I also ran this script on URLs beginning with http, and the program gave the desired output. However, it still doesn't pass the test.

Comment: if you are able to get html file with curl.. & then you are able to get pdf filename then why didn't you `wget` it...
Are you able to see correct pdf file names first you confirm

Comment: Yes, as I wrote, the URLs are stored correctly. Wget can't work with URLs of the type I need : file://path/to/file.html

Comment: @Ashish Curl with -O also does the download.

Comment: Try putting quotes around the URL in the curl statement..? Also `echo $PDFURLU` for debugging since that is what you are trying to access... Are you missing a `$` on `PDFURLU` in the `while read` statement?

Comment: @beroe I said already that $PDFURLU always stores the correct value. This means I have already done debugging.

Comment: Well, it is not working so there is some debugging left to do. [Your last comment has three close brackets?]

Comment: @beroe, sorry =) Yes, I made a mistake, didn't want to offend you

Comment: @beroe, and thanks, the first automated test passed!

Comment: I'd really be surprised if `if [[ $PDFURL == *http* ]]` is doing what you want/think. Review your code with the idea that the block of code for that test is not getting executed. Good luck.